# Random number generator gives weird results

Tags: java, random, cursor

I have this class that first stores the current coordinates of the mouse cursor, then creates two random integer numbers x and y both are between -10 and 10 and then moves mouse cursor horizontally and vertically on the amount that equals those generated numbers respectively.

```
public class Test {
            private static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            private static int width= (int) screenSize.getWidth();
            private static int height=(int) screenSize.getHeight();
            private static int currentX=(int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
            private static int currentY =(int)  MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

            public static void main(String[] args)  throws java.awt.AWTException {

                    Robot robot=new Robot();
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int xMove;
                    int yMove;
                    int[] resultArray=new int[10000];
                    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)  {
                        refreshCoords();
                        xMove=random.nextInt(20) - 10;  // - 10 to 10
                        yMove=random.nextInt(20) - 10;
                        robot.mouseMove(currentX + xMove, currentY + yMove);                                                                      
                        resultArray[i]=xMove;
                    }
                    System.out.println(sumArray(resultArray)); //returns - 4000/-5000
                }

                private static void refreshCoords()  {
                            currentX=(int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
                            currentY=(int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
                }

                private static int sumArray(int[] resultArray)  {
                            int result=0;
                            for (int i=0; i<resultArray.length; i++)  {
                                result+=resultArray[i];
                            }
                            return result;
                }
}
```

The thing is, although I expected the mouse cursor to mostly stay at the same place or move across the screen gradually and not too far, the mouse cursor tends to move to the upper left corner no matter where it was first located. I can't figure out what is wrong here, why does this happen? I would think that if with each loop the mouse cursor moves - 10 to 10 to the right/left and to the top/bottom it would wander randomly across the screen, not take liking of some particular position/corner. I summed all the horizontal moves and it gives a big negative number (-4000+ or -5000+) indicating that the cursor indeed tends to move to the left border.

Comment: `nextInt(20) - 10` gives a random number between -10 and +9 (inclusive), giving an average of -0.5, i.e. slow move towards upper left. To get number between -10 and +10 (inclusive), you need to use `nextInt(21) - 10`.

Comment: @Andreas, wow, that's crazy! Such a small difference in the maximum possible number caused such great diviation and trapped the cursor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextInt(20)` will produce a uniformly distributed value between `0` and `19`. Thus `nextInt(20) - 10` will produce a value between `-10` and `9`. As you can see, the mean of such a distribution is `-0.5`. Performing `N` such random selections will have a mean of `-0.5N`. In other words, over time, you'll see the sum drifting towards the negative, and since you're using the same random function for your X and Y coordinates, the point will drift towards the upper left corner.

You should use `nextInt(21) - 10`, which will produce a uniformly distributed value between `-10` and `10`, and get the result you expect.